# SharePoint List Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, json-formatting

I need to do a databar format on a choice column with text inside. Is this possible? I can get it easily enough with the given JSON formatting code but i cannot seem edit the code below enough to where it gives me why I need. My choice are New, Approved, Scoping, and Completed.

`{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "8px",
        "white-space": "nowrap"
      }
    }
  ],
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-field-dataBars"
  },
  "style": {
    "padding": "0",
    "width": "=if(@currentField >= 20, '100%', (@currentField * 5) + '%')"
  }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this one help you?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "8px",
        "white-space": "nowrap"
      }
    }
  ],
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-field-dataBars"
  },
  "style": {
    "padding": "0",
    "width": "=if(@currentField == 'New', '25%', if(@currentField == 'Approved', '50%',if(@currentField == 'Scoping', '75%','100%')))",
    "box-sizing": "border-box"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thats why all the crap i tried didnt work. I was nesting the ifs differently. I spent way too long on this last night. thank you.